# Зачем определять метод как статический?

Tags: python, ооп, методы

Скажите, а есть в питоне какой-то практический смысл определять метод как статический с помощью декоратора @staticmethod ?

Почему нельзя определить его как обычный метод и просто никак не использовать self? Это хуже по производительности? Или это просто соглашение, чтобы добавить больше ясности в код?

UPD: Наверное, я не очень ясно сформулировал суть вопроса. Понятно, что если нужно использовать метод без создания экземпляра, то метод нужно делать статическим.

Но я часто в чужом коде вижу, что класс по логике может быть использован только через создание экземпляров. И всё равно многие методы определяют как статические только потому, что их результат не зависит от self, а только от переданных аргументов. Хотя всё равно этот метод всегда будет вызываться только внутри экземпляра.

Есть ли смысл делать так?

Comment: [ответы на данный вопрос в англоязычной вресии SO...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438473/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-static-methods-in-python)

Comment: Если вам нужно выполнять какой-то код класса вне зависимости от существования объекта этого класса, то можно задать метод как `@classmethod`. Если метод вообще никак не зависит от класса, в котором он описан (к примеру, когда класс выступает просто "контейнером" или "неймспейсом" для каких-то методов), то можно сделать метод статическим.

Comment: По поводу дополнения к вопросу - у меня PyCharm метод подчеркивает, когда его можно сделать статическим, и не отвяжется, пока ему не дашь то что он хочет)

Answer (score 2):

Фабрика классов, например. И похожие сценарии.

```
class Processor():
    @staticmethod
    def create(typeof: type):
        if typeof == str:
            return StringProcessor()
        elif typeof == int:
            return IntProcessor()
        raise ValueError('unsupported type')

class StringProcessor(Processor):
    pass

class IntProcessor(Processor):
    pass

proc1 = Processor.create(int)
proc2 = Processor.create(str)
```